# SetFileAttributeW source code in c++

Tags: c++, fileapi, file-attributes

I tried to access to source code of SetFileAttributeW API, but my efforts is not successful. Any one can guide me how to acquire its source code in c or c++?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any one can find SetFileAttributeW definition in https://doxygen.reactos.org/db/dbb/winbase_8h.html#a560dd934948dbe3bc4b252dec29b3c4e.

Best.